# Is it possible with CSF firewall, to forward IP traffic transparently?

Tags: iptables, dnat, relay

In /etc/csf/csf.redirect

```
10.100.100.115|*|10.200.200.186|*|tcp
10.100.100.115|*|10.200.200.186|*|udp
```

I have the following config, now when I connect to https://10.100.100.115/ (nginx+php) with script `<?php echo  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>` I see the server IP, is it possible to reroute it with client IP? So for example I connect from my home IP, let's say 10.0.50.50 it would show 10.0.50.50 instead of the redirected server?

Important to note that only and HTTP/HTTPS solution will not be sufficient (so no X-header solution) since I want to connect to different protocols TCP UDP which are not restricted to HTTP(S) only. So basicly I want a universal transparent proxy so the server @ 10.200.200.186 will see the Client IP instead of the server IP (10.100.100.115), I hope this makes sense and is doable in one way or the other. I cannot use plain iptables since this apparently is blocked by CSF firewall, which is in use by DirectAdmin, and for security's sake I am not willing to disable CSF, it does auto block using LFD for x failed auth attempts, which is pretty useful for blocking bruteforcing clients.

Comment: `ens3:0` is not a virtual NIC. It's an additional address on ens3 with a label, existing only to please the (obsolete on Linux) ifconfig tool that can't handle multiple IPv4 addresses on the same interface because it uses an obsolete Linux kernel API. So trying actions considering it as an interface will fail one way or an other. The first step to avoid this mistake is to never again use the ifconfig command (but instead ip link + ip addr).

Comment: alright, will do that, use ip link + ip addr, but can what I want be done in some way, I don't mind if it's another tool then IP tables, on windows I use winiprelay for this purpose (it works on lower level networking, not the winsock API which comes with all kind of overhead and restrictions set by an app on what to forward and what not), works like a charm, not sure how to do it on Linux though.

Comment: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.10:53` will redirect port 53 to a new destination, if that is what is asked? (remind to adjust udp to tcp if needed)

Comment: thx djdomi, I did try it, but it does not allow me to forward the port using the Debian IP or IP 2

Comment: What does "it does not allow me to forward the port¨ mean actually? What did you do? What is the error message when you did it?

Comment: There is no error message, rule goes in iptables, but it does not forward the port, not port 80, not port 57913, and no UDP ports, ofc I altered -p tcp --dport to 80 and :53 to :80 it simply does not work, maybe because of CSF v14.20, the Debian 12 machine is running DirectAdmin.

Comment: please show us the command you tried , and give please `iptables -L` and `iptables-legacy -L` the output

Comment: nope, also did disable CSF, still no succes.

Outputs will be edited in mainpost for readability

Comment: commands used now are:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.100.100.115 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.200.186
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.100.115 -j SNAT --to-source 10.200.200.186

Comment: Note that CSF and LFD are distinct services. You can normally run LFD alone if you want. AFAIK CSF is actually a wrapper around iptables, and it ships with some preset rules. Then it adds rules on the fly in iptables to block offending IP addresses. There is nothing that prevents you from using iptables but rule order is important.

Comment: I guess what I want is simply not possible with just forwarding, since if it's a middle server, and if forward the sourceIP, it tries to communicatie directly back with the clientIP/SourceIP, SYN ACK issues, I think I add the server on distance to a openVPN solution and asign a public IP to it from within the datacenter, a little bit (or quite a bit) of extra CPU usage, but it works.

Comment: Thanks Kate, it seems setting up the pre and post.sh which is included in CSF for setting up things like custom iptables rules before or after applying the other iptables, does not work either, whatever I do with iptables rules, it just does not work somehow, maybe CSF (using iptables) is blocking the ports somehow which are needed to be open, for now I give up on this iptables solution and focus on other things, it works via openVPN now, maybe I will give it another try later, or if someone is still able to point me in the right direction.